# Passing MS-Access string >255 characters to MS-Word field

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I'm using `.FormFields("WordBookmarkName").Result = stringFromAccess` method to pass data out of MS-Access to an MS-Word document.

It seems it can only pass up to 255 characters. Is there a way I can pass more to my field in MS-Word?

**Edit:**

*This is a simplified version of the code I was using that works ok up to 255 characters:*

```vb
Dim startForms As String
Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document

startForms = String(256, "x")

Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 'Set appWord object variable to running instance of Word.

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    Set appWord = New Word.Application 'If Word isn't open, create a new instance of Word.

End If

Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open("C:\myFolder\MyForm.docx", , True)

With doc

    .FormFields("wdStartForms").Result = "" 'Clear anything currently in the form's field
    .FormFields("wdStartForms").Result = startForms

    .Visible = True
    .Activate

End With

Set doc = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing
```

*JohnnyBones: this is the code I adapted after your answer; using `ActiveDocument` wasn't working, so I continued to use the `doc` reference I'd made and it seemed to work ok with 256+ characters after that:*

```vb
Dim startForms As String
Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document

startForms = String(256, "x")

Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 'Set appWord object variable to running instance of Word.

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    Set appWord = New Word.Application 'If Word isn't open, create a new instance of Word.

End If

Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open("C:\myFolder\MyForm.docx", , True)

With doc

    .FormFields("wdStartForms").Result = "" 'Clear anything currently in the form's field
    .Bookmarks("wdStartForms").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = startForms
    .Visible = True
    .Activate

End With

Set doc = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing
```

Comment: THe index would typically be 1: with FormFields the name/bookmark typically "covers" the FormField and nothing else. So its range "covers" 1 field, and the index is for the "nth" field in the range, not the document as a whole. In theory the bookmark can be moved (but that arguably creates an "error state" in the form), and AFAICR in theory it is possible to nest fields inside the FormField, which might change the index. But I have hardly ever seen it.

Comment: ahh ok, good to know :) `.Fields(1)` does populate my field when its 255 characters, but not when it's 256. I've been testing by passing `String(255, "x")` and `String(256, "x")`.

Comment: actually, it wasn't populating, I had just commented-out the wrong bit

Comment: what kind of improvments of your solution you expect? your second code is working very nice, so...?

Comment: I put the bounty on because I initially couldn't get the answer I ultimately accepted to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use:

```
Dim FmFld As FormField, Str1 As String
Str1 = (a long string > 256 characters)

Set FmFld = ActiveDocument.FormFields(1)
FmFld.Result = Str1
```

You get an error: “String too long” (a ridiculous “design” feature, given that you can do it manually without problems!).

Same if you use:

```
ActiveDocument.Formfields("Text1").Result = Str1
```

You can get round this by using:

```
ActiveDocument.Unprotect
FmFld.Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Str1
ActiveDocument.Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True
```

Or if you're referring to the formfield by name:

```
ActiveDocument.Unprotect
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Text1").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Str1
ActiveDocument.Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True
```

You could also try passing multiple strings and concatenating them, chopping each string into chunks less than 255 characters.

Comment: Thanks Johnny. I couldn't get this to work though - see edit in my original question.

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to get it working by referring to the `.doc` reference I'd made rather than active document :)

Comment: BTW Unless you are Dave Rado you should at least credit the source of this solution, i.e. http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/SetLongFmFldResult.htm .